# Access wamp server of laptop using numeric IP address with subdomain in the url

Tags: wamp, subdomain

My laptop and android mobile are connected to same router. I am able to access wamp running on my laptop using http://192.168.1.108/ but i want to access it like http://test.192.168.1.108/.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not possible. You are using an IPv4 numeric address in the form od x.x.x.x - there can only be 4 octets with the exception of an optional port number. If you want to add a textual sub-domain component then you are going to have to set up a DNS server and use the DNS name, i.e., test.mydomain.com. The only other possibility is to use something like NAT or to use PAT with port routing to your specific sub-domain.

Comment: Also I've removed references to Android as there is nothing directly relevant to Android in your question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to get a DNS service like noip.com.  You can get an DNS address of whatever is available and point to a server in your own network, i.e. 192.168.1.108. I do this all the time.